# Splitting dataframe by month on a series in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has dates that range from month 1-12 for every set. The data looks like:

```
     Date         AB      AK      AR      DC
  0  2005-01-01  267724 37140   152536  60004
  1  2005-02-01  214444 32710   149821  49280
  2  2005-03-01  205938 27484   141526  41345
  3  2005-04-01  99262  14562   81254   31609
  4  2005-05-01  66059  8172    50241   18705
  5  2005-06-01  33556  4880    27216   11796
  6  2005-07-01  28057  4138    20156   9126
  7  2005-08-01  25466  3892    19005   8262
  8  2005-09-01  26819  3923    18776   9480
  9  2005-10-01  60849  5942    31255   1664
.
.
```

The Date is in `datetime` format:

```
data_res_num.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 164 entries, 0 to 163
Data columns (total 11 columns):
Date                   164 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

But when I try to pass only certain months (10 to 3) with:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month > 10) & (df['Date'].dt.month < 4)]
```

I get an empty frame for df.

I thought it may have been the range but even if I set it `==` certain month it also gives me an empty frame.

How can I select the range from November - March?

Comment: Typo: there are no integers greater than 10 AND less than 3.

Comment: That's the thing. I also tried `df = df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.month == 10) & (df['Date'].dt.month == 4)]` and I get the same result and I know 10 and 4 exist.

Comment: @jpp pandas will select rows which satisfy either of these column conditions, they don't have to be satisfied simultaneously...

Comment: @Dascienz, With `&` ("AND"), yes they do.

Comment: @jpp, Oh duh, he needs a `|`, my bad! Haha, really embarrassing.

Comment: Yes. Corrected with `|` but what is this joining operator do and why did `==` not work?

Comment: Hey @HelloToEarth, `|` is an `OR` operator which means that pandas will select rows which satisfy either condition, however, when you use `&` which is an `AND` operator it means that both conditions must be satisfied simultaneously. You can't have a month be greater than 10 and less than 4 at the same time, nor can you have a month that is both equal to 4 and 10 at the same time. Therefore, you need to use the `OR` operator, `|`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Dascienz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try slicing without the use of `.loc`:

```
df = df[(df['Date'].dt.month > 10) | (df['Date'].dt.month < 4)]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem is a typo, see comments to the question.